# Kendo dropdown default placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using kendo drop down, the drop down has only one element right now.

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list id="download" 
 ng-model="vm.downloadType"
 k-data-text-field=" 'Name' "
 k-data-value-field=" 'id' "
 k-option-label="'Select'"
 k-data-source="vm.Options"
 k-rebind="vm.Options"
 ng-change="vm.DownloadChanged()"/>                               


 vm.Options= [{ id: 'one', Name: 'Show')}];
```

Now the drop down loads and the place holder "Select" is seen, i click and select Show from dropdown and some action is performed, I now want the drop down to show Select i.e placeholder again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `DownloadChanged()` function, just *reset* the widget's value:

```
this.value("");
```

Being `this` the current widget.

[Working demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iMaLE).

Comment: @user1076698 it seems to work for me. Select `Show` option and wait for a second. It will change back. That is an example of *how to reset drop down list value*.